# How to get rid of "noise" in a plot image

Tags: r, image, plot

What could I do, so the plot doesn't lose quality, after it is automatically saved?

The following code will be an example of plot and save:

```
data.barplot <- c(80L, 60L, 80L, 40L, 40L, 0L, 80L)

jpeg("/home/machina/Dropbox/Vitor-IC/graficos/teste.jpeg",width = 2600, height = 2800, quality = 100, pointsize = 70)
barplot(data.barplot, ylab = "Percentage: Days of Holidays", names.arg = c("Sun","Mon", "Tue", "Wed","Thu", "Fry", "Sat"))
title(main="Title Here",outer=T, cex.main = 2.4)
dev.off()
```

The result was a very bad quality image. Thus, could you help me improve it, so it can barely be pleasurable to see?

The generated image is the one bellow.

### Note:

I played with the input variables in `jpeg` function such as `quality, res, height, width, pointsize`, but didn't get the improvement I was aiming for
[image: barplot]

Comment: Try to use `png()` rather than `jpg()`.

Comment: @jaySf, it wasn't enough :|

Comment: `pdf() ...dev.off()`

Comment: Remove `outer=T` from your `title` statement so that the title will not be cut off.

Comment: try vector graphics instead of raster graphics such as jpg. pdf or svg as suggested above will not reduce quality

Comment: The pdf format seems the best from all. It solved my problem

Comment: The `cairoDevice` package can greatly improve the quality of saved plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default units is pixel `units=px` meaning you cannot increase  the quality by using `res` (for instance) because the number of pixels is constant!

Change the units, for instance:

```
data.barplot <- c(80L, 60L, 80L, 40L, 40L, 0L, 80L)
#
jpeg("teste.jpeg",width = 7, height = 7, units = "in", res = 300)
barplot(data.barplot, ylab = "Percentage: Days of Holidays", names.arg = c("Sun","Mon", "Tue", "Wed","Thu", "Fry", "Sat"))
title(main="Title Here")
dev.off()
```

Now, increasing `res` will change the number of pixels and thereby the quality of your image (and the size of the file), try `res=600`.

Hope this will be of help.